# How to add a timer in wx.App MainLoop that updates Window objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, python-multithreading

Is there a way to put a timer or a hook into MainLoop to call some methods in some wx windows every 1 second?

I can put timers inside a wx.Frame object but I want to put a timer *outside* those objects. Is there a way to do so?

If I start a thread and try to do that I get:

```
self.updateThread = Thread(target = updateWindows, args=[self])
self.updateThread.start()        
app.MainLoop()


Pango:ERROR:/build/pango1.0-EzEh0I/pango1.0-1.38.1/./pango/pango-layout.c:3925:pango_layout_check_lines: assertion failed: (!layout->log_attrs)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And adding a `updateThread.join()`:

```
self.updateThread = Thread(target = updateWindows, args=[self])
self.updateThread.start()
self.updateThread.join()

app.MainLoop()
```

Nothing gets drawn on the screen.

UPDATE: to clarify, in Python a Timer IS a thread, so I'll use whathever is better for the task (timer or thread). I want to update N number of Window object every N seconds.

wx widgets has its own timers but they should be binded to Window object, so I would need N wx.widgets timer for N Window objects and that's not what I want.

Comment: why do you need a thread? can you just do without it?

Comment: It's really not clear what are you asking: do you want to use timers or threads or both? What exact problem do you have with the timers (hint: they're not inside or outside of anything)?

Comment: I'll update the description. Basically I want to update the windows every X seconds. A Timer IS a thread in Python, so whathever is better for the task is useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution that avoids using timers and creating your own threads would be to use `wx.CallLater`

```
def poll(self):
   do_something()
   # waits 1 seconds before calling again
   wx.CallLater(1000, self.poll)
```